# grafana/loki-stack how can i add grafana tempo

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-tempo

I'm trying to customize the trace display using Grafana Tempo. I use helm grafana/loki-stack https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/. Installing command  `helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack  --set grafana.enabled=true,prometheus.enabled=true,prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false,prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,loki.persistence.enabled=true,loki.persistence.storageClassName=managed-premium,loki.persistence.size=250Gi -n logs`

But when I add the setting  `tempo.enabled=true` nothing happens. Could you please tell me how can I add tempo when deploying this stack? Or how can I add it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you've made an assertion that if you can 'enable' Prometheus, you can simply 'enable' Tempo.

If you have a look at the corresponding Helm directory for loki-stack you can see that Tempo is not in the values.yaml unfortunately. (At this point in time)

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/5b2dacdfe93fa306d83302455890b9deb7f814a0/charts/loki-stack/values.yaml

To add it you would need to create and maintain your own Helm chart for loki-stack with Tempo.